# Uneven wear on tire rim (V-brake set up)

Tags: rims, wear

I've noticed that the wear on my tire rim is uneven. The black indicator groove is still visible in some places, but worn down in other places.
Both the left and right side braking surfaces have this uneven wear, and, where one side is worn down (indicator line no longer visible), the opposite side still has the line visible.
I thought that the wheel might be out of true, but after inspecting the wheel the best I could, that doesn't seem to be the case, and the wheel doesn't have any noticeable wobble.

Is this how braking surfaces on rims normally start to wear out, or does it indicate a problem?
Does anyone have any thoughts on whether it is time to replace the rim/wheel?

[image: uneven wear on tire rim]

Comment: How much difference in wear is there? All wheels have some wobble, but it should be less than 1mm sideways movement. Use the rim brake pads as reference point when checking for wobble. Make sure the brake pads are not rubbing on the rim (maybe they did at some point?).

Comment: The difference in wear seems to be 0.5 mm (which is roughly the depth where the groove is deepest), and then the worn sections (where the line has disappeared) are even with the rest of the rim. I've checked the wobble, and it looked like it was under 1mm (or 1mm at max).

Comment: There are three worn sections on the rightside rim, and three worn sections on the left side. The rim was second hand when I got it, but was in good shape, with an even groove, and since I've had it, I haven't had problems with the brakes rubbing on the rims.